# Retrive MAC Address with IP Address by using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to retrieve the MAC Address with IP Address...

```
var nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    .Where(ipProp => ipProp.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
                     .Where(ip => ip.Address.ToString().Equals("192.168.1.111"))
    );
```

I am getting an error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'"

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? :) EDIT: Now there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(ipProp => ipProp.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.Address.ToString().Equals("YOUR_IP")) != null).FirstOrDefault();
if (networkInterface != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(networkInterface.GetPhysicalAddress());
}
```

Comment: Oh thank! If want this line return MAC Address not NetworkInterface, can it be ?